# How to Select Multiple days in JQuery fullcalender Week Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to select multiple days in select event of jQuery fullcalender in week option. It is working in month option, same thing I want in week option. In week option, it is possible to select only one day.

How to select multiple days with from time and to time options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in the `all-day` section in the week-mode. This is the first row - just below the displayed days of the week.

Comment: i need Same not In All Day Section with in Time Range Section